# Panels overlay capability

Tags: panels, modal-dialogs

I'm building with D7 and looking for an easy way to build a page rendered into an overlay.

Wouldn't it be awesome if Panels could be configured to spit out it's contents into an overlay -perhaps the core admin overlay.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Is it worth building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Panels under Settings -> Basic for your page there is a checkbox with the label "Use this page in an admin overlay." that you can use for this.